# How can the Neron-Tate height pairing be considered an intersection number?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Given the Neron-Tate height $\hat h$ on an elliptic curve we defined the associated bilinear form:
$$\langle P,Q\rangle = \frac{1}{2} \bigl( \hat h(P+Q) - \hat h(P) - \hat h(Q) \bigr) $$
My professor offhandedly mentioned that this form can be considered a sort of "intersection number", or specifically when $P=Q$ a self-intersection number. The notation certainly seems to suggest it, but I can't immediately see why. How is Neron-Tate an intersection number?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.2050.pdf

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/101595/questions-on-n%C3%A9ron-tate-canonical-height

Comment: It might be useful to look at 8.4, 8.5 from "On the Mordell-Weil lattices" by Tetsuji Shioda. See also thm 4.1 from [Explicit arithmetic intersection theory and computation of Néron-Tate heights](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.06791.pdf), which refers to Faltings–Hriljac's works.

Comment: A very useful reference is theorem III.9.3b), p. 247, in Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves by Silverman. See also Proposition 4.3.1. in Ulmer's Lectures on curves and Jacobians over function fields. The relation between heights and intersection pairing is most easily understood when you look at elliptic curves over _function fields_.

Comment: See also  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/54708

Comment: The relation between height and intersection product is made very explicit and clear when one looks at elliptic curves $E$ over function fields $k(C)$ (where $C$ is some smooth projective irreducible algebraic curve). Then the height pairing $$\langle P, Q \rangle = - D_P \cdot D_Q$$ equals the (negative of the) intersection product between two divisors $D_P, D_Q$ with _rational_ coefficients. This is stated as theorem III.9.3b), p. 247, in Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves by Silverman, as I mentioned above.

Comment: (Over number fields, I guess one has to deal with arithmetic intersection theory or Arakelov theory, see maybe  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/54708 . Intuitively in this context, the projective curve $C$ gets replaced by the $1$-dimensional scheme $\mathrm{Spec}(\Bbb Z)$ (but it is not a proper scheme!)).

Comment: [If you are interested that I turn all these comments into an answer, please let me know. Hopefully then the answer will be useful to you / accepted by you].